# A question about an error in svydesign function : FPC implies >100% sampling in some strata > in RSTUDIO

Tags: r, error-handling, survey

I have a question about the `svydesign` function and an error that occurs `FPC implies >100% sampling in some strata >`

I created this dataframe as an example  (*dnum = district number represents* **the first stage cluster** and *snum = school number represents* **the second stage cluster**). As I understood, when specifying clusters, we also need to specify the population size in each cluster in **fpc1** and **fpc2**.

```
library(survey)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(111)
mood = sample(c("happy","neutral","grumpy"),
            size = 1000,
            replace=TRUE,
            c(0.3,0.3,0.4))

set.seed(222)
sex = sample(c("female","male"),
            size=1000,
            replace=TRUE,
            c(0.6,0.4))

set.seed(333)
age_group = sample(c("young","middle","senior"),
            size=1000,
            replace=TRUE,
            c(0.2,0.6,0.2))


status = data.frame(mood=mood,
                    sex=sex,
                    age_group=age_group,
                    income = trunc(runif(1000,1000,2000)),
                    dnum = rep(c(441,512,39,99,61),each = 200),
                    snum =  1:1000 ,
                    fpc1 = rep(200,1000) ,
                    fpc2 = trunc(runif(1000,5,10))
                      )
```

when creating the design

```
design = svydesign(ids=~dnum+snum,
                   fpc = ~fpc1+fpc2,
                   data=status)
```

the output is :

```
record 1 stage 2 : popsize= 5  sampsize= 200 
Error in as.fpc(fpc, strata, ids, pps = pps) : 
  FPC implies >100% sampling in some strata
```

What is this error referring to (knowing that I did not sepcify any strata)? and how to deal with such error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that in the first record it looks at for stage 2 you say you have a population size of 5 but the sample size in the data set is 200. That is, you say that the number of sampling units in the population (`snum` values) is 5, but your data set contains 200 of them.

That's going to be the first record of the lowest-numbered PSU, which is `dnum==39`

```
head(subset(status, dnum==39))
      mood    sex age_group income dnum snum fpc1 fpc2
401 grumpy female    middle   1966   39  401  200    5
402 grumpy female    middle   1778   39  402  200    9
403 grumpy   male    middle   1753   39  403  200    7
404 grumpy female    middle   1110   39  404  200    8
405  happy female    middle   1047   39  405  200    9
406 grumpy female     young   1878   39  406  200    9
```

It does indeed say `fpc2` is 5, so it's saying there are 5 different `snum` values in the population for `dnum==39`
There are indeed 200 observations in the sample with different `snum` and with `dnum==39`

```
 length(unique(status$snum[status$dnum==441]))
[1] 200
```

so the population size at stage 2 must be at least 200.

There's another problem. These 6 rows are all in the same PSU (number 39), so their `fpc2` value should be the number of `snum` values in the population with `dnum==39`. This means they should be the same, which they aren't.

`fpc1` is the number of PSUs in the population (in the stratum that record belongs to, if you have strata, otherwise overall).  That is, at stage 1, you have sampled the 5 units in the sample from a total of `fpc1` units in the population

`fpc2` is the number of second-stage sampling units in the population, in the cluster that record belongs to (and in the stratum within that cluster, if there's stratification at stage 2).  That is, at stage 2, you have sampled the 200 units in the sample from a total of `fpc2` units in that PSU in the population.